# Winui ListView reorder introduces multiple selected items

Tags: listview, winui-3

If we try to reorder items in a listview then an extra item is being selected, making two selected, occurs when `SelectionMode = "Single"`

```
<ListView
    AllowDrop="True" 
    SelectionMode="Single"
    CanReorderItems="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0" Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0" Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

see demo github [repo](https://github.com/tinmac/DnD_Test)

Disclosure: 
I have posted as a possible bug on WinUI github page but im wondering now if this is the correct way to implement reordering?

[image]

Comment: It does look like a WinUI 3 bug.

Comment: To my surprise, I cannot reproduce but you can also submit the issue at https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Did you try my demo repo that I linked above? You got me wondering if its my enviroment.

Comment: Yes, Use your demo without change. ;)

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Ok so after some more checking it seems to work fine on Windows 10 but the bug appears on Windows 11 using  exact same packaged demo app on Hyper-V test machines

Comment: I did test on Windows 11. [I test it again now just in case missing something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA2fG.gif).

Comment: Thinking it was my enviroment I re installed W11 on my laptop (from USB stick, erase all partitions) , then installed the demo (VS not installed) and got the error!! I mean what the heck

Comment: There is a workaround on the issue [page](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/8739) sadly its hacky